# Unable to execute Headless Geckodriver with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

Since I implemented the Headless configuration on my Test I received this issue: java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried to to switch to other types of implemantation for the Gecko Headless, but none of them worked

```java
@BeforeTest
public static void OpenBrowser () {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","binaries/geckodriver"); 
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
    firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("-headless");

    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
    driver.get(...

}
```

Once the test is executed I receive th3 following error: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands to get it running in headless mode are as follows:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

You'll probably want to have the `WebDriver driver` part defined outside the test so that you can perform the following in your `@BeforeTest` like so:

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest 
public static void OpenBrowser() {
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setHeadless(true);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question please accept it as the correct answer/upvote it.